# multicol package has no effect on footnote

Tags: footnotes, multicol

I have an article like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 0}
\textbf{This is a description}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]

Some text\footnote{I want to play in column.}
Again\footnote{ABCD}
\lipsum[3-4]
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The footnote is outside two columns.

[image: footnotes are outside columns]

But I want it to be inside like this:

[image: inside footnote]

I could solve this with `twocolumn documentclass. However, the section will be inside the column.
How can I lay the footnotes inside column and keep the format of the section and description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed in the documentation for `multicol` e.g., `texdoc multicol`. Basically a requirement for column footnotes conflicts with a) balancing and b) different number of columns on a single page.

There are in theory possibilities to design solutions for special sub-cases, but that hasn't been done and is not likely to happen. So in short `multicol` has the restriction that footnotes always have the full width.

Comment: Is there a way I can try to do with `twocolumn`? Can I keep the position of the section and description?

Comment: Not really with standard methods. \twocolumn[...] gives you single column material on the top of the page (but it will start a new page so one can't use it in the middle of the document without manual effort.